# UINavigationBar is Moved Up After UIImagePickerControllerDidCancel?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a problem where I modally present a UIImagePickerController from a UINavigationController and the user presses cancel instead of taking a photo. I dismiss the view from the UIImagePickerControllerDidCancel callback, however when I return to the previous view the entire view (including the navigation bar) is moved up several pixels. The other thing that is extremely odd about it is that when I select a text field on that view, the keyboard is displayed partially offscreen. This only happens on my iPhone (I present it in a popover controller for the iPad and that has no problems).

Here is my code for the didCancel callback:

```
-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];  
    }
    else//for iPhone
    {   
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];    
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use this line:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

In place of this line:

```
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference. From [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW103): "If you call this method on the presented view controller itself, it automatically forwards the message to the presenting view controller".